# JSONException: Value <!--?php of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I want to consume JSON data generated by a PHP file(news.php) from the Android end. I have a PHP file which seems to generate the JSON data properly and my Android side works fine. The problem is I get the above-mentioned exception.

What's really puzzling me is if I copy the JSON details output produced by the PHP file onto a separate file and save it as a JSON file (e.g news.json), my Android app is able to consume the JSON data, but if I repoint it to the php (news.php) file I receive the above exception.

I have looked at other possible duplicate questions but they don't quite fit my own. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a php file which encodes to JSON format:

```
<?php

include("includes/db_connection.php");          

if (isset($_GET['latest_news'])) {
    $limit = $_GET['latest_news'];      
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c, tbl_news n WHERE c.cid = n.cat_id ORDER BY n.nid DESC LIMIT $limit";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}   

$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($total_records >= 1) {
    while ($link[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $set['RecentNews'] = $link;
    }
}     

echo $val = str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

//}

?>
```

Then I have an 'Android JSON class' Code snippet:

```
try {
    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(Constant.CATEGORY_ARRAY_NAME);
    JSONObject objJson = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        ItemLatest objItem = new ItemLatest();
        objItem.setCId(objJson.getString(Constants.CATEGORY_ITEM_CID));
        objItem.setCategoryName(objJson.getString(Constants.CATEGORY_ITEM_NAME));
        //objItem.setCategoryImage(objJson.getString(Constants.CATEGORY_ITEM_IMAGE));
        objItem.setCatId(objJson.getString(Constants.CATEGORY_ITEM_CAT_ID));
        objItem.setNewsImage(objJson.getString(Constants.CATEGORY_ITEM_NEWSIMAGE));
        objItem.setNewsHeading(objJson.getString(Constants.CATEGORY_ITEM_NEWSHEADING));
        objItem.setNewsDescription(objJson.getString(Constants.CATEGORY_ITEM_NEWSDESCRI));
        objItem.setNewsDate(objJson.getString(Constants.CATEGORY_ITEM_NEWSDATE));
        arrayOfLatestnews.add(objItem);
    }
}
catch (JSONException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Android 'Constants class' code snippet:

```
public class Constants implements Serializable {

    public  static final String SERVER_URL = "http://192.100.1.1:4000/news";

    public static final String LATEST_URL = "http://192.100.1.1:4000/news/news.php?latest_news=10"; 

    public static final String CATEGORY_ARRAY_NAME = "RecentNews";
    public static final String CATEGORY_NAME = "category_name";
    public static final String CATEGORY_CID = "cid";
    public static final String CATEGORY_IMAGE = "category_image"; 
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

JSON Output:

```
{"RecentNews":[{"cid":"7","category_name":"World","category_image":"91771_world.jpg","status":"1","nid":"9","cat_id":"7","news_heading":"World Sample News Heading","news_description":"
World Sample News 

\r\n","news_image":"88702_IMG_5038.JPG","news_date":"08-16-2017","news_status":"1"},{"cid":"12","category_name":"IT","category_image":"98162_IMG_1303.JPG","status":"1","nid":"8","cat_id":"12","news_heading":"IT Sample News Heading","news_description":"
IT Sample News 

\r\n","news_image":"24966_IMG_5018.JPG","news_date":"08-03-2017","news_status":"1"},{"cid":"5","category_name":"Business","category_image":"4591_download.jpg","status":"1","nid":"7","cat_id":"5","news_heading":"Business Sample News Heading","news_description":"
Business Sample News 

\r\n","news_image":"13015_IMG_5017.JPG","news_date":"08-02-2017","news_status":"1"},{"cid":"4","category_name":"Sports","category_image":"22814_sports.jpg","status":"1","nid":"6","cat_id":"4","news_heading":"Sports Sample News Heading","news_description":"
Sports Sample News

\r\n","news_image":"72021_IMG_5016.JPG","news_date":"08-01-2017","news_status":"1"}]}
```

Comment: Can you show the output of http://192.100.1.1:4000/news/news.php?latest_news=10

Comment: I have updated the question and added the JSON output data

Comment: Are you sure the json output you posted is the same as one received by the application? An error message you got says that result string started with "<!--?php" which looks like broken php openning tag. Maybe try to log content of your result variable in android code (Log.d("mytag", result)).

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Carriage returns and line feeds must not appear in string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *josef.adamcik*, i used Log.d("tag", result) to get a log of the exception and it highlighted it was indeed reading a php file that started with " `<!--` ".

The 'db_connection.php' file 'included' in the news.php file had a section in it starting with `<!--comments -->` and upon removing this section everything worked well.

EDIT:

I had used `<!--comments-->` in php for multi line comments instead of `/* comments */`

Because i was using Brackets IDE, it grayed out the `<!--comments-->` section anyway and i overlooked that it was wrong.

Comment: But.. comments in php are made with '//'.

Comment: Thanks @DebanikDawn , i haved editted the answer above and im sure it should be more clear now